# How to install and set up MySQL in an Ubuntu Docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu

I try to create a Docker container with an installed MySQL and several other things to create environment for e2e testing.

My idea is:

1. install every neccessary things into a container,
2. import a database dump,
3. run my tests,
4. generating reports
5. and so on...

...inside one single container. I think this isn't the better way, but the first 2 steps is required to start building a working solution.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Budapest /etc/localtime

RUN apt install -y tzdata libterm-readline-gnu-perl

RUN dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata

RUN echo "mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server/root_password password secret" | debconf-set-selections \
    && echo "mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server/root_password_again password secret" | debconf-set-selections

RUN apt install -y mysql-server

RUN mysql -uroot -psecret -e 'USE mysql; UPDATE `user` SET `Host`="%" WHERE `User`="root" AND `Host`="localhost"; DELETE FROM `user` WHERE `Host` != "%" AND `User`="root"; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;'

RUN /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

And the result is:

```
Building containername
Step 1/10 : FROM ubuntu:20.04
 ---> 26b77e58432b
Step 2/10 : RUN apt update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 32aba1dda06d
Step 3/10 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b7de58c246b3
Step 4/10 : RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Budapest /etc/localtime
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 00149bd68213
Step 5/10 : RUN apt install -y tzdata libterm-readline-gnu-perl
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4b4162d08ed3
Step 6/10 : RUN dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 36529216283e
Step 7/10 : RUN echo "mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server/root_password password secret" | debconf-set-selections     && echo "mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server/root_password_again password secret" | debconf-set-selections
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 532e9640e40f
Step 8/10 : RUN apt install -y mysql-server
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0c44dc58b319
Step 9/10 : RUN mysql -uroot -psecret -e 'USE mysql; UPDATE `user` SET `Host`="%" WHERE `User`="root" AND `Host`="localhost"; DELETE FROM `user` WHERE `Host` != "%" AND `User`="root"; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;'
 ---> Running in 556f5cf75cc3
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
ERROR: Service 'containername' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c mysql -uroot -psecret -e 'USE mysql; UPDATE `user` SET `Host`="%" WHERE `User`="root" AND `Host`="localhost"; DELETE FROM `user` WHERE `Host` != "%" AND `User`="root"; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;'' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How can I install & setup MySQL in the docker container with a custom defined user?

Comment: While you are building the image, nothing is running, you are just adding layers (copying files). In step 8 `mysql-server` will not start and in step 9 you will not be able to connect to it.

Comment: Is there any way to build a working environment with mysql user, password, and import a dump file programmatically?

Comment: Why don't you just use the official image from [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)?

Comment: because I want to install not just MySQL, but Chrome & nginx too to run cypress or nightwatch in the container. I didn't choosed yet. I build a multitenancy app with several specific settings, so I want to create a container as a virtual machine to run tests. Later I want to add some config options to simulate different environments... it's a little bit complicated project I think.